# Apache .htaccess subdomain redirect + path proxying (rule chaining?)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, mod-proxy

I've got a tricky question, as far as I see it ;)

Currently, I'm in setup of a dynamic branch release pipeline which already takes a branch during pipeline processing and deploys it on our test server in a reserved folder ("branches").
Our wildcard domain points towards it.

Currently working (in the branches folder):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}/public [L,NC]
```

But the problem now is, that for example a domain **my-new-testbranch-123.domain.com** get's the redirect to **my-new-testbranch-123.domain.com/my-new-testbranch-123/public/**. This is on one side ok (because out data is being found there, but I want to have a proper url such as the app can be routed properly. So I tried to rewrite the url via proxy. But without luck.
Any suggestions?

My goal would be to use the subdomain  my-new-testbranch-123.domain.com/ without any additional path in url. The document root is located in  my-new-testbranch-123/public/.

I tried via chaining, but both did not work as I thought -.-:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}/public [NC,N]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^.]+)/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%{REQUEST_URI}/public [NC,C]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^.]+)/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
```

(with C and N flags)

Best,
Bent

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your original rule is you don't have `/` after `public` and since that is an actual directory, Apache is doing a 301 redirect via `mod_dir` module.

You can use this rule to fix the issue:

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/public%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser or via command line curl to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: Well, partially.
It's now working in terms of all assets etc. but I still get the path /my-new-testbranch-123/public/ and if I'm opening the site, via path it's not working either: my-new-testbranch-123.domain.com/projects

Comment: So to say, the second criteria (proxying the path) is not yet fulfilled

Comment: Do you have any other htaccess or other rules in this htaccess?

Comment: nope, this is the full file (my version above - now with trailing /)

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.